# Proving set property in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Are there anyone who can help me proving the following?

Let $f\colon S \to T$ be a function. Prove that
$f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$ and $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$, for all $A, B \subseteq S$.

Comment: There's almost an algorithm for proving that sets are equal to one another, in basic set theory. If you need to prove that $X=Y$, first prove that $X\subseteq Y$, then prove that $Y\subseteq X$. If you need to prove that $X\subseteq Y$, then write "Let $x\in X$" and try to prove $x$ is in $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general $$C\subseteq D\implies f(C)\subseteq f(D)$$ I preassume that's obvious to you.

Based on that rule we find that: $f(A),f(B)\subseteq f(A\cup B)$ and $f(A\cap B)\subset f(A),f(B)$.

This can of course also be expressed by: $f(A)\cup f(B)\subseteq f(A\cup B)$ and $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$.

It remains to be shown that also $f(A\cup B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$.

If $y\in f(A\cup B)$ then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in A\cup B$.

If $x\in A$ then $y\in f(A)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$ and if $x\in B$ then $y\in f(B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$.

Shown is now that $y\in f(A\cup B)\implies y\in f(A)\cup f(B)$.

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

If $y\in f(A\cup B)$ then $y=f(x)$ for $x\in A\cup B$, in particular, $y\in f(A)\cup f(B)$. The converse is obvious since $f(A),f(B)\subset f(A\cup B)$. And thus $f(A)\cup f(B)\subset f(A)\cup f(B)$.

Let $y\in f(A\cap B)$. Then $y=f(x)$ for $x\in A\cap B$. In particular, $y\in f(A)$ and $y\in f(B)$ what prove the claim.